# Since updating animejs my javascript no longer functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, animation, anime.js

Essentially I had an 'animejs' animation trigger when the nav button is clicked and then the same animation would reverse after a second click. It would toggle. Now this no longer works after updating animejs.

I've tried using a variable such as
var playing = true; and to toggle between it but that doesn't possess the same functionality as before.

the code looked something like this (this is simplified)

```
var navAnimation = anime.timeline({
duration: 100,
});

animation.add({
targets: 'navStuff'
//animation would be here
});

document.querySelector('.nav').onclick = () => {
animation.play();
// animation.play still functions properly
animation.reverse();
// animation.reverse(); is broken
};

//before the update you could simply place a two methods within the onclick function and it would toggle between them but that no longer is the case with animejs
```

What I want to happen is to be able to use a single target (button) to open my navigation and close it (toggle between the two state). I want to be able to spam the button and not see and glitches (as before).

Answer (score 0):

Please beleive me I've spent an uncessary amount of time trying to get this working and it just refused to giv in.

I've attempted working with heights / transforms / colors, variable diffs, close inspection. Nothing works.

This is how I animate "reverses" now:

```
const notificationsContainerElement = document.querySelector('#demo-install-notifications-container');

let notificationsContainerAnimation = anime({
    targets: notificationsContainerElement,
    height: '350px',
    easing: 'easeOutElastic(1.5, .5)',
    duration: 1500,
    delay: 0,
    autoplay: false,
});

notificationsContainerElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(notificationsContainerAnimation.began === false) {
        notificationsContainerAnimation.play();
    } else if(notificationsContainerAnimation.began === true) {
        notificationsContainerAnimation.began = false;
        anime({
            targets: notificationsContainerElement,
            height: '100px',
            easing: 'easeOutElastic(1.5, .5)',
            duration: 1500,
            delay: 0,
        });
    }
});
```

My first animation is `autoplay: false`, then, when I click an element, I `.play()` that animation, but notice the checks for the original animation's `began`. Once you hit play on an animation, the `began` property keeps changing.

Right...

But just doing `notificationsContainerAnimation.reverse()` on my animation just doesn't work no matter what. It just doesn't. **I strongly believe it has to do with anime not being able to get where it's supposed to actually reverse to - the values.**

The logic is sound, there's no way why it shouldn't work...but it doesn't.

So, for now, use 2 animations.